# Freemarker: convert from date to POSIX time

Tags: date, posix, freemarker

How to convert from date to POSIX time?

Date format isn't important("2016-02-12", "May 3, 2017 7:45:00 PM" and any other).

ps. I need to get past day,so i decided to convert it to posix and substract  86400.

Answer (score 2):

This is available as a built-in since 2011.

> `?long` now works for date, date-time or time values, and returns the
>   milliseconds since the epoch (as `java.util.Date.getTime()`).

See: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/versions_2_3_17.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have the value as a `String` (not a `java.util.Date`), first you need to convert it to a value of type date or date-time (to `java.util.Date` basically). That's done as `myString?date` or `myString?datetime` respectively, and the `date_format` or `datetime_format` FreeMarker configuration settings must match the format used in `myString`. Alternatively, you can specify the format ad-hoc, for example as `myString?datetime('MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a')`. See http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_setting.html#topic.dateTimeFormatSettings for more information about date/time/datetime format strings. Also, as there's no time zone information in your sample strings, you must ensure that the `time_zone` configuration setting is set to the time zone where the strings should be interpreted.

Now that you have the date or datetime value, you can convert it to *milli*seconds since the UNIX epoch as `myDateOrDateTime?long`. POSIX uses seconds though, so then you need `(millisSinceEpoch / 1000)?floor`.

So the longest possible expression is like `myString?datetime('MMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss a')?long / 1000)?floor`, but certainly you will want make a FreeMarker `#function` out of that.

Also note that FreeMarker by default prints numbers for humans, so it might prints something like `1,493,865,900`. To prevent that, apply `?c` at the end of the expression.

Comment: For `.now` it's even easier, as it's already a "datetime", not a string: `(.now?long / 1000)?floor`